# PyOpenGL Glut Window

Tags: pyopengl, freeglut, glutcreatewindow

So I recently started to use PyOpenGL's GLUT module and cannot find any simple tutorials on it (links to any would be appreciated) and I just want to create a glut window using `glutCreateWindow('window')`, but as soon as the window pops up it disappears. I tried using `glutMainLoop()` in my main function but it just gives an error.

```
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *

glutInit()

def main():
    glutCreateWindow('window')
    glutMainLoop()

if __name__=='__main__':main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html) callback. The glut main loop invokes the display call back.

Minimal example:

```py
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *

glutInit()

def display():
    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0) # red
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    # your rendering goes here
    # [...]

    glutSwapBuffers()
    glutPostRedisplay()

def main():
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA)
    glutCreateWindow('window')
    glutDisplayFunc(display)
    glutMainLoop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

[`glutInitDisplayMode`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html)  sets the initial display mode. [`glutSwapBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html) swaps the buffers of the current window ant and thus updates the display. [`glutPostRedisplay`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html) marks the current window as redisplayed and therefore causes the display to be continuously redrawn, which is necessary for animations.

See also [Immediate mode and legacy OpenGL](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/readme/content_python_legacy.md)